# Core actions added to a Screen Flow doesnt open pop up page

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a Lightning visual flow with 2 core actions in it. Core actions are based on object specific actions. when i run the flow i am expecting that core actions will open up the pop up page for data entry similar to what i get when i launch the object specific action from a button. But it doesnt happen and flow gets executed successfully without popping up any page for data entry. Please let me know what is behaviour of core actions inside a screen(interactive) flow

Answer (score 0):

Had a call with salesforce.com support. Core actions wont open pop up page. Core actions are used to perform actions inside the flow and screen needs to be designed by developer